# js get by tag name not working

Tags: javascript

i want to resize all the images inside div test but its not working here the script and html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function x(){
    var  yourdiv =  document.getElementById('test');
    var  yourImg =  decoument.getElementsByTagName('img');
        yourImg.style.height = '400px';
        yourImg.style.width = '300px';
    }
</script>

<div  id="test">
<img alt=''  src='imges/book1.jpg' />
<img alt=''  src='imges/book2.jpg' />
</div>
```

Comment: If this is the real code then the problem is 'decoument' on the 4th line.

Comment: thats the div style   <style type="text/css">
#test img
{
height: 1000px;
width: 1000px;
}
</style>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName('img');` returns a node list not a single element

```
    var  yourImg =  document.getElementsByTagName('img'); // both img tags in this list
    yourImg[0].style.height = '400px';
    yourImg[0].style.width = '300px';
```

Comment: Not to mention he mispelled document as decoument.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, thanks I forgot to change it in the second spot

Answer (score 1):

List of issues

1. Syntax error: `decoument` should be `document`.
2. you are finding the `#test` element but never use it to filter the images inside it..
3. `getElementsByTagName` return a list, so you need to iterate over the elements in that list..

All issues fixed with

```
function x(){
    var  yourdiv =  document.getElementById('test');
    var  yourImg =  yourdiv.getElementsByTagName('img'); // use yourdiv and not document to only search for images inside the yourdiv element
    for (var counter = 0; counter < yourImg.length; counter++) { // loop the list of images
        yourImg[counter].style.height = '400px';
        yourImg[counter].style.width = '300px';
    }
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/dCSsP/

Answer (score 0):

use array in js problem fixed..:)
function over()
{

```
var x=document.getElementById("p1");
alert(x.innerHTML);

var s = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
alert(s[0].innerHTML);
s[0].innerHTML="changed";

x.innerHTML="text is change successfully ";
```

}